# What's the best marker in a video for recognition?

Tags: opencv, video, image-recognition

I'm currently building an automatic synchronisation processing between a video track (coming from a camera) and an audio tracks (coming from a micro). 
To do that, I plan to build a small web application who will display a clapper with my smartphone (Ex: Iphone) and emit a specific bip when I will be filmed.
After that, I will execute a small OpenCV application (JavaCV in reality) which will detect the image where my smartphone has displayed the clapper. It will remain for me only find the specific bip to synchronise the two tracks.

You can see here(http://vimeo.com/47002882) and here(http://vimeo.com/46213073) videos that we have already built and synchronise manually. Based on this context (distance, lighting, etc of the previous videos) What is it for you, the best thing (shape, color or other) that can be detected almost all the time ? And what kind of transformation, I should use ?

You must imagine that I will display the clapper from my smartphone with a camera who will be placed at five-seven meters from me.

I built a first basic clapper (http://jsbin.com/zuqumiso/45/) and used a video treatment with OpenCV like that :

Frame -> a RGB to GRAY conversion -> GaussianBlur -> AdaptativeThreshold -> Hought Transformation (standard) to detect the lines.

But it's efficient only when my smartphone is at thirty centimeters from the camera...

Comment: When you film the screen of the smartphone from 5-7m away, approximately how wide (in pixels) is the screen in the video ?

Comment: We can take video up to 14.2 megapixels (4608 x 3072 pixels)

Comment: that's the dimension of the video frames, but what is the dimension of the phone screen observed in the video ?

Comment: Oh, I don't know, I will measure tomorrow, I keep you in touch.

Comment: Hi @AldurDisciple, I just get back the camera and make a test. In reality, the camera produce videos of 1920x1080 (4608x3072 is just for photo) and I measure that my screen smartphone is approximately 16x26 pixels wide.

Answer (score 4):

Given the very small size of your phone screen in the video, I do not think that you will be able to automatically detect any standard marker (e.g. QR codes, circles or chessboard) displayed on the phone.

**If I were you, I would try with a much simpler approach**. I would start by displaying a fullscreen blinking black and white pattern on the phone. If the phone is kept reasonnably steady, this should enable detecting the blinking area as the area where intensity variance is highest on a few successive frames. Then, for audio/video synchronisation, I would simultaneously emit the bip and turn the fullscreen pattern into a specific color (e.g. bright red or bright green). Again, this transition from black/white to fully saturated color should be detected quite easily, by detecting the color saturation discontinuity on the blinking area identified previously.

This might not be what you were after when asking this question in the first place, but given your tight constraints on phone/camrea distance, I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: I think that given the size of the phone within the image, this is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most image algorithms work by looking at transitions (aka; edges). As your camera is a RGB camera, the ideal detectable edge would be an edge that is visible for all colors.

Th easiest option would be to use a simple QR code. It's edges are easy to detect and you can even destinguish between multiple codes.

Shape and color tend to be quite a bit more fickle then QR codes.

Comment: Thank you Nallath, the QR Code is not a bad idea, but it seems more used for closed recognition, like with a camera of a smartphone who detect the pattern at few centimeters. This solution really works at seven meters of distance ? What post-treatment and algorithm you recommend me to do this ? I think use a Gray conversion, then a Threshold and to finish a SURF algorithm.

Comment: It would depend on the resolution of the image and the size of the QR code. Making the QR code as simple as possible would also increase the detection rate. 

You might even try to use the checkerboard calibration method of openCV with a very small (eg; 3x3 squares) checkerboard. If the camera is calibrated you can use solvePNP to get the orientation & rotation of the board with respect to the camera.